# Getting "javax.servlet.ServletException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /servlet/" error bcz of IE dialog box

Tags: spring-mvc, servlets, websphere, filenotfoundexception

Getting

> javax.servlet.ServletException: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
> SRVE0190E: File not found: /servlet/

error repeatedly although my application is working just fine.
Using WAS 9

update:
I figured out, This error is coming only when I click on "open" button on IE dialog box. This box is shown when I click on any PPT or Excel file in my application.
using:  response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", sAttach + "filename=" + p8Doc.getFilename(iPage));

How to fix this?

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.